# Replacing flow switch on Titan water heater

Tags: repair, water-heater

I need to replace the magnetic flow switch on my Titan tankless water heater...Do I insert it from the side like the diagram shows, or do I need to open the panel?

[image]

Comment: Is there a opening on the side that you could remove and replace it ? With the water off I hope. Would taking the cover off make it easier?

Comment: Txs @EdBeal I just watched an extremely unhelpful youtube, and it seems that the valve can be accessed from the cold water inlet side with tweezers. I was worried about destroyng the filter. The Titan.com website is worthless...

Comment: @cascabl  make that an answer and accept it, it may help others in the future, explain the process step by step turning water off unscrewing and using the tweezers you will probably get some additional upvotes.

Comment: I have had 3 of these over the last 10 years...I think I will take pics and describe my solution. @EdBeal Txs for your suggestions, and yes I will post a self-answer.